# How to count based on where in mysql? php

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, count

I was wondering how can I make a query that will show the counts that I need using codeigniter?

EX: Submitted to select 90 and 56

```
$this->db->where('atr_id', 90);
$this->db->or_where('atr_id', 56);
```

List_table

```
   id     |    item_id    |   atr_id
---------------------------------------
   1      |        1      |    56
   2      |        1      |    90
   3      |        2      |    56
   4      |        2      |    90
   5      |        2      |    92
```

The expected return would look like this.

```
    item_id    |  active_attr   |  total_attr  
----------------------------------------------
        1      |        2       |     2        // active_attr (90,56) and total_attr (90 , 56)
        2      |        2       |     3        // active_attr (90,56) and total_attr (90, 56, 92)
```

The `active_attr` counts the number of `atr_id` found (90, 56) in an `item_id`

And the `total_attr` counts the total number of `atr_id` of an `item_id`

Need really help here thanks guys...

Comment: Could you please clarify how `active_attr` results in 2 for `item_id` 2?

Comment: @DarshanMehta `active_attr` are 56 and 90 found

Comment: See my update with CI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `GROUP BY`, and this SQL query can give your expected return at one time.

```
SELECT a.item_id, COUNT(DISTINCT a.atr_id) as active_attr, 
COUNT(DISTINCT b.atr_id) as total_attr
FROM test2 a
INNER JOIN test2 b ON a.item_id=b.item_id
WHERE a.atr_id=56 OR a.atr_id=90
GROUP BY a.item_id
```

And this is the ci query sample.

```
<?php
    $res = $this->db
              ->select('a.item_id, COUNT(DISTINCT a.atr_id) as active_attr, COUNT(DISTINCT b.atr_id) as total_attr')
              ->join('test2 as b', 'a.item_id=b.item_id')
              ->where('a.atr_id', 56)
              ->or_where('a.atr_id', 90)
              ->group_by('a.item_id')
              ->get('test2 as a')
              ->result();
```

Comment: I tried and it worked! Thank you! :) just curious who has better performance with @thomas-g

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with this query

```
SELECT item_id, 
       SUM(
           CASE 
                    WHEN atr_id = 90 THEN 1
                    WHEN atr_id = 56 THEN 1
                    ELSE 0              
                END
            ) AS active_attr, 
            COUNT(*) AS total_atr
FROM List_table
GROUP BY item_id
```

So you don't need a WHERE clause, the counts of your `active_attr` is done in the SELECT with the CASE statement. The CASE will return 1 for your submitted values (56 and 90) and 0 for the rest, you then SUM all the 1s to get the count.

Comment: is there any way this would be in codeigniter format? I tried it in sql line and it works :)

Comment: I am sorry but I have no knowledge in codeigniter. SQL FTW :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the *facets* (or classification) of the result.

I would use your first query, read the result-set with a loop and populate the two facets (two maps) with a single scan.

```
$item_facet = array();
$atr_facet = array();

foreach($query->result() as $row){
    $item_id = $row->item_id;
    $atr_id = $row->atr_id;
    $item_facet = increment($item_facet, $item_id);
    $atr_facet = increment($atr_facet, $atr_id);
}

function increment($map, $id){
    if(isset($map[$id])){
        $map[$id] = $map[$id] + 1;
    }else{
        $map[$id] = 1;
    }
    return $map;
}
```

Alternatively these are two `GROUP BY` SQL queries

Answer (score 0):

did you apply group by method:

```
 $this->db->group_by('item_id'); 
 $this->db->order_by('item_id', 'desc');
```

This will produce a result like

```
|  ITEM_ID |  TOTAL  |
|    12    |    3    |
|    15    |    2    |
```